# When RowsAdded event is fired?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, event-handling, datasource

I have two tabs in my form. The second one contains the DataGridView. I press "Open" button on the first tab and data is added into the table.
I have added Console.WriteLine(e.RowsCount) into RowsAdded event listener, so I get this, as expected (for 4 rows):

- 1 row(s) added
- 1 row(s) added
- 1 row(s) added
- 1 row(s) added

Then I switch to the second tab in order to see my table. Then interestring things occur.

- 4 row(s) deleted (RowsDeleted)
- 1 row(s) added
- 3 row(s) added

Please, tell me how can I avoid this? I have extra code in my listener and that can lead to unexpected behaviour if RowsAdded event is fired when it isn't meant to be fired.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.RowCount + " row(s) added"); 
            if (e.RowCount == 1) {
                if (ID3v2FrameChoiceList.Items.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value)) ID3v2FrameChoiceList.Items.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            }
            ID3v2FrameChoiceList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

P.S> My datagridview is bound to the datasource.

Comment: When you create an object with rows and columns the counts are intially -1.  The row count stays at -1 until columns are added and then goes to one.  I think I would change your code to e.RowCount >= 0.  Not sure why you are using just One.

Comment: OK. But how to avoid event firing when I switch between tabs?

Comment: Why is data being added to the DGV when you switch tabs?  You should only be getting the event when data is added.  The issue is not switching tabs. The issue is the adding of the data.  The instance of the DataSource must be different in the two tabs.

Comment: No, for some reason event fires exactly when I switch to the second tab that contains my DataGridView. Maybe thats because DataGridView was not displayed yet? It's strange that rows are deleted and then added again.

Comment: From my tests, the reason you see the _“4 row(s) deleted”_ … is because the grids `AllowUserToAddRows` property is set to `true.` … When you set the grids `DataSource`, it will fire the rows added, then rows deleted event for each column of the data source. In addition, IF the grid is NOT displayed (shown) when the grids data source is set, then in reality, the columns have NOT yet been drawn in the UI because it was not displayed (shown).

Comment: If the grid was not displayed when its data source was set, then when you click on the tab page that contains the grid, THEN… the grid IS FINALLY SHOWN (displayed) and the rows added and deleted events will fire again when drawing the grid. You need to keep in mind that much of the DRAWING of the grid and UI commands will be ignored IF the grid is NOT displayed. In this case, it will do the UI commands WHEN the grid IS displayed to the user.

Comment: In other words, if you set the “visible” tab to the tab page with the grid like…  `tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[“tabPageWithGrid”];` … BEFORE you set the grid’s `DataSource` and then, set the “visible” tab page back to the original tab page AFTER the grids data source has been set, THEN, when the tabs are displayed and you click on the tab with the grid, then the grid events will NOT fire again as you are currently seeing.

Comment: It is unclear “where” the data is loaded into the grid in relation to the posted code. However, IF you make the tab with the grid “visible” when setting its `DataSource` as described above, then when you click on the add rows button in the other tab page, the console will ONLY display the added rows. Where/When is the grids `DataSource` set and… IS the grid displayed to the user when its data source is set? When using tab pages, some of the UI commands will be ignored IF the tab page is NOT visible.

Comment: DataSource is attached when I press button on the first tab, so grid is not visible yet

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, I have to switch to the tab that contains grid before assigning DataSource and then switch back? But user sees flashing while tabs are automatically switching, doesn't he?

Comment: The "flashing" should be pretty quick and I doubt if the user will complain. But I guess that would depend on how much data there is.

Comment: Thank you! But do you know any neater solution?

Comment: I suspect you hve two instances of the DataSource and you should only have one.

Comment: A have just one Datasource and underlaying BindingList

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _”neater.”_ … As we already know, the grids event will fire multiple times depending on if the grid is displayed or not. Can you move the button(s) and any code that is addressing the grid to the tab where the grid is? Without knowing the bigger picture of what you are trying to do… it will be difficult to proffer a different solution.